# Catching an exception to throw another one, not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony

I have something like this in a Symfony controller:

```
try {
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Entity::class)->findOneBy(['uuid' => $uuid]);
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // die('Invalid uuid'); <- this works
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Resource not found...'); // this doesn't work
}

if(!$campaign) {
    // this works if the uuid has a valid format but doesn't exist in db
    throw $this->createNotFoundException($this->get('translator')->trans(Utils::NOT_FOUND_STRING));
}
```

I want to show an error 404 and not a 500 if the user opens a page with an invalid UUID. 
The exception is caught, because if I put a die() it works. But with `throw $this->createNotFoundException(`, I get:

> ConversionException
>
> Could not convert database value "55012772-4801-4e26-8..." to Doctrine Type uuid_binary

Comment: Why the distinction? Not found is not found. If you really need this I would suggest you perform validation and throw an exception as needed before passing unknown data to Doctrine.